# Fetching data from multiple databases with MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli, multiple-databases

i'am using MySQLi to connect and fetch data from my MySQL server with
`$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","database_1");`
I have a file that used for connection and data collection (dboperations.php) from above database
Now , i need to connect another database (e.g. database_2) and fetch data in the same php file.
Conditions:
Are databases on the same server? YES
Am i authorized to connect with same username and pass? YES
Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: There are 10 kinds of people: ones who google and ones who ask strangers to google for them

Comment: i am one kind of the people who searchs internet but cannot get the proper way of do it. Maybee i missed correct one but i think this site for asking the programming questions and getting answers. Even maybee one of people will see this thread and find correct answer from there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [mysqli::select_db](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) to switch databases on the same server:

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database1');
```

then

```
$link->select_db('database2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM database_2.table ...
```